# Scroll element into view at bottom of page

Tags: javascript

I have a large table of data and when an item is chosen from it, I want to bring the submit button, which is below it, into view.

Currently I have been using:

```
elb = document.getElementById('buybox');    
elb.scrollIntoView(true);
```

This brings the element into view at the top of the page, but, I only want it to be brought into view, say, 10% from the bottom of the page so the table data is still there and the simple page shift shows the user the button is there.

Is this possible?

Its difficult to measure content heights as they differ from page to page.

I'm using native javascript, not with the JQuery library.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `scrollIntoView(false)` =)

Instead of bringing elb to the top, it brings it to the bottom of the page =)

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.scrollIntoView)

Comment: Well I never! Who knew! Thanks for that, will post full answer too for anyone interested

Answer (score 3):

Posting full answer to include 10% from bottom issue:

```
var screenh = window.innerHeight; 
var toScroll = ''+screenh/10;
elb.scrollIntoView(false);
window.scrollBy(0,toScroll);
```